# How does Rabbeinu Yonah permit a Issur D'Oraisa of אונאת דברים based on a passuk in Nach?

Tags: rabbeinu-yonah

In  the עליות דרבינו יונה to Bava Basra (quoted at the end of sefer Chofetz Chaim).  He says although the Torah forbids (ridiculing someone) לא תונו - it is certainly permitted and actually a מצוה to ridicule one who has sinned but hasn't (won't do?) teshuvah - he derives this from a passuk in Mishlei 28:4 "שומרי תורה יתגרו בם" - (Q#1) technically how can a passuk in Nach supercede an issur in the Torah? (Q#2) Where does he get this from I found a Gemara in Berachos 7b/Megillah 6b which permits direct confrontations with a רשע - but seems to be very different from what RY is permitting?

quote from עליות דרבינו יונה

כדתניא לא תונו איש את עמיתו באונאת דברים הכתוב מדבר. הא כיצד היה בעל תשובה לא יאמר לו זכור מעשיו הראשונים, ותניא כל הפוסל פסול ואינו מדבר בשבחו של עולם. אבל **ודאי בדברים שבינו לחבירו**, שאין לו תקנה עד שיעשה תשובה או ירצּה את חביהו, והוא אינו מרציהו, **או בשאר עבירות שאוחז בהם ועושה אותם במזיד, ועודנו מחזיקּ בהם ולא במקּרה, אבל הם מדרכיו ולימודו, **מצּוה לגנותו** בפני כל אדם שנאמר עוזבי תורה יהללו רשע ושומרי תורה יתגרו בם, **וכדי שיתרהקו בני אדם מדרךְ רשע** וכמ"ש ושומרי תורה יתגרו בם, **וכדי שישוב גם הוא** מדרכיו ויתקן מעשיו, על זה אמרו כל מילתא דמיתאמרא באפי תלתא לית בה משום לישנא בישא ומותר לו לאומרה אם הוא יודע שהדבר אמת

Comment: From Rabbeinu Yona language it seems he’s referring to the mitzvah of tochacha since this is a case where the person won’t change unless he’s publicly admonished https://www.sefaria.org/Chofetz_Chaim%2C_Aliyot_d'Rabeinu_Yonah%2C_from_the_Shitah_Mekubetzet.4?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: @Chatzkel - How does he know that the mitzvah of rebuke supercedes the לאו of לאו תונו.  Does it supercede other לאוין.  Especially since the הקיש of הוכיח תוכיח to לא תשא עליו חטא implies the opposite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In reverse order,

Q2:

> Where does he get this from

Rav Hinana ([Baba Mesia 59a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.59a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) describes the scope of the prohibition as only applying to shomre miswoth (those observant of miswoth), as only they are properly called עמיתו:

> אמר רב חננא בריה דרב אידי: מאי דכתיב "ולא תונו איש את עמיתו" – עם שאתך
> בתורה ובמצוות אל תונהו"
>
> Rav Hinana, son of Rav Idi, says: What is the meaning of that which is
> written: “And you shall not mistreat each man his colleague
> ('amitho)”? [The word 'amitho is interpreted as a contraction of 'im
> ito, meaning: One who is with him.] With [one who is] with you in
> [observance of] Torah and miswoth, you shall not mistreat him.

The [Hagahoth Maimonioth (H. Mekhirah 14, 4)](https://rambam.alhatorah.org/Parshan/Hagahot_Maimoniyot/Mekhirah/14.4#m7e0n6) wrote:

> תניא ולא תונו איש את עמיתו עם שאתך בתורה ובמצות לא תונהו. למדנו שלא
> הזהיר הכתוב באונאת דברים אלא ירא השם. ואמר במדרש, שאם הונה עצמו, אתה
> רשאי להונהו, שאין קרוי עמיתך
>
> It was taught that you should not mistreat your colleague if he is with
> you in Torah and miswoth. We have learned that the Torah does not warn
> against Onath Debharim except against those who awe God. And the
> Midrash says, that if he mistreats himself you are permitted to
> mistreat him, for he is not called your colleague.

Q1:

> how can a passuk in Nach supercede an issur in the Torah?

When R. Yonah quotes Mishle, this serves merely as a sort of asmakhta. It is not the source of the law (the scope of which is defined above), rather it is scriptural allusion that resonates with the same/similar concept. Accordingly, this ought not be interpreted as an occasion where a passage in Nakh is being used to supercede a Torah prohibition.

In the comments you write regarding R. Yonah's position that:

> It seems as though... he's referring to a case of a one time sin...
> that would be pretty extreme to categorize him as יצא מכלל עמיתך - for
> the one sin

R. Yonah states ([Gate 3, sec. 219](https://www.sefaria.org/Shaarei_Teshuvah.3.219?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> ואם החוטא איש אשר איננו ירא מלפני האלהים. כמו הפורק מעליו עול מלכות
> שמים. ואינו נזהר מעבירה אחת אשר כל שער עמו יודע כי היא עבירה. מותר
> להכלימו ולספר בגנותו. כך אמרו רבותינו (ויקרא כ״ה:י״ז) אל תונו איש את
> עמיתו. עם שאתך בתורה ובמצות אל תונהו בדברים. ואשר לא שת לבו אל דבר ה'
> מותר להכלימו במעלליו ולהודיע תועבותיו ולשפוך בוז עליו. ועוד אמרו
> מפרסמין את החנפים מפני חלול השם. אבל אם נכשל בחטא על דרך מקרה. ורוב
> הימים דרכו להשתמר מעונו. אין לגלות על חטאו
>
> And if the sinner is one who does not fear God, such as one who casts
> off from himself the yoke of the Kingdom of Heaven, and is not heedful
> of a certain transgression which is known to be a transgression by all
> the others of his fellow men, it is permitted to humiliate him and to
> speak degradingly of him. As our Sages have said in relation to the
> verse, "and ye shall not wrong one another" - "If one is with you in
> Torah and miswoth, you shall not wrong him with words." If one however
> does not apply his heart to the word of God, it is permitted to
> humiliate him through his deeds, to make known his abominations, and
> to pour shame upon him. And they have said further. "Hypocrites should
> be exposed to prevent desecration of the Name". But if one falls into
> sin by chance, and most of his days is wont to guard himself against
> transgression, his sin should not be revealed.

Making it clear, that in his estimation it is inapplicable to a single fleeting sin, but rather to a specific type of character with an entire disposition of the personality. In order to be open to such criticism, this individual must flagrantly violate a law which is undeniably known by all of his coreligionists, do so as a pattern of behavior, and in a way that demonstrates that he is פורק מעליו עול מלכות שמים (casts off from upon himself the yoke of heaven).

This type of individual (הפורק עול) is described in greater detail by R. Yonah earlier ([Gate 3, sec. 143](https://www.sefaria.org/Shaarei_Teshuvah.3.143?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> וענין הפורק עול כגון הכופר לאכול נבילות או לאכול חלב ודם או לחלל
> יו"ט. ואף על פי שאינו עובר על שאר המצות. אחרי אשר הסיר מעליו עול אזהרה
> אחת, כבר מרד בשם יתעלה. אמנם כי גם פעמים הצדיקים נכשלים בחטא אחד אבל
> אין זה בלתי על דרך מקרה. בהתגבר עליו היצר. ונפשו מרה לו על הדבר. ונזהר
> ממנו אחרי כן. אבל האומר בלבבו לפרוק מעליו עול אזהרה אחת כל עת אשר
> יתאוה לעבור הוא הנקרא כופר לדבר א'.
>
> "Removal of the yoke" refers to a denial by which one permits to
> himself such things as eating a carcass, suet, or blood, and
> desecrating the festivals. Although he does not transgress the other
> miswoth, still, by having removed from himself the yoke of one of
> exhortation, he has rebelled against the blessed Name. It cannot be
> denied that the righteous, also, sometimes go astray in respect to a
> particular sin, but when they do, it is the result of circumstances,
> of their having been overpowered by the evil inclination, and they are
> bitter over what they have done, and keep from doing so again. But one
> who entertains in his heart the thought of removing from himself the
> yoke of one exhortation whenever he desires to transgress, is called
> "an unbeliever in respect to one thing."

Comment: re: Q2 - You might be right, but It seems as though re: בין אדם לחבירו - that he's referring to a case of a one time sin) "מי שקובל על חבירו בעבירה שעושה חבירו"  (re  בין אדם למקום it's different) - who has not done teshuvah (hasn't returned the $ or ask for forgiveness) - that would be pretty extreme to categorize him as יצא מכלל עמיתך - for the one sin

Comment: @Chaim I've edited the post to reflect your concern and clarify R. Yonah's position.

Comment: In ST219 that you mentioned where it's only allowed if he's a פורק עול - he states that this is in regards to one who has illicit relations (בין אדם למקום), and for the reason that he's not part of עמיתך (thus excluded from the אונאת דברים prohibition).  He points out that other categories of sinners (e.g. the 1 timer) would not be permitted to shame. 
 However, before the case of ערוה, he mentions that a witness is allowed to testify against someone who stole,etc - i.e. שבין אדם לחבירו - (no concern for the embarrassment it's cause אונאת דברים) and not specific to a פורק עול- i.e. עמיתך

Comment: i.e. I think the answer is a great answer, and I've clicked to accept it as my Q didn't distinguish between בין אדם למקום vs. לחבירו.  However, I think the answer only addresses בין אדם למקום.  Whereas בין אדם לחבירו RY seems to allow publicly revealing the sin (thus embarrassing the sinner) while the sinner is still בכלל עמיתך - so long as he hasn't done teshuvah (same split seems to be in עליות דרבינו יונה where he only describes the פורק עול in regards to non monetary.  Likewise in ST221 he concludes that even outside of beis din, and even for non-monetary בין אדם לחבירו matters

Comment: I don't believe that there is a distinction to be made between בין אדם לחבירו/למקום here. When R. Yonah mentions the case of theft, he raises it as an exception to the general idea he endorses that one should not individually testify against their fellow (i.e. for naught). In the case of theft, the individual witness is instead obligated to swear to their testimony in lieu of a second witness. These are the demands of justice so that the victim will be restored. Other such occasions where an individual has witnessed the commission of sin (be it בין אדם לחבירו or למקום), he should not testify.

Comment: (1) Sorry I wasn't clear.  I agree - RY allows/commands public shaming of one who is פורק עול whether it's בין אדם למקום או לחבירו - and the source of the heiter is b/c not עמיתך, re: the elevation to mitzvah multiple sources are mentioned.  However, he also mentions that it's allowed to publicize that someone (a NON פורק עול) stole to help get the $ back).  as being בין אדם לחבירו - we can know that he hasn't done teshuvah (money not returned).  My Q - even if he hasn't done teshuvah -he's not פורק עול and still עמיתך what happened to אונאת דברים?  Why is it lifted?

Comment: (2) (side note on a point you mentioned re: the oath - I think that עד אחד מחייב שבועה that he's referring to is that 1 witnesses' testimony is enough to force the accused to either swear (he didn't take the $) or give it back and thus the testimony is thus is not for naught (i.e. a front to defame someone)

Comment: I would suggest that uniquely in the case of theft, the need to restore the victim is דוחה the prohibition of אונאת דברים. It is an exception, not the rule.

Comment: As regards (2), I think you are correct - that the defendant makes the oath, not the sole witness. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: re: (1) - that's exactly my question - it seems intuitively obvious, but technically - why does the need to restore $ to the victim override the עבירה of אונאת דברים?  Can he מחלל שבת to do it too?  There's a court system to resolve such matters.  The courts require 2 witness, thus in cases with only 1 witness - where is the source that we override עבירות in order to prevent a gap in the court/justice system? (btw thanks - I'm enjoying the discussion)

Comment: I can only speculate on the reasoning. Perhaps where the prohibition of אונאת דברים has the potential to serve as a מכשול it is inoperative. The thief has an obligation to restore the victim (חייבה אותו תורה לשלם), however often (usually?) without external prompting he will not. So the singular עד has a dilemma. Testify and thereby engage in אונאת דברים, or refrain from אונאת דברים and allow it to stand as a מכשול to the thief who must make the victim שלם. This however is subject to refutation, as the thief then may double down and engage in שבועת שווא...

Comment: I'm glad we've been able to distill down the question and sharpen it up... and honestly, I do not know if there is a textual source or whether this is RY's own hiddush. The discussion has been mutually enjoyable and beneficial. Thanks for raising the question and your input :)

Comment: Also - part of the original Q - see the quote from עליות דרבינו יונה just added to the OP - you can see that ikkar is determined if he has done teshuvah - re: בין אדם לחבירו - you can see if he's returned or asked for forgiveness, whereas בין אדם למקום you have to infer it from his overall behavior / actions.  Thus the stipulation that he continually does the sin is mentioned only re: בין אדם למקום - however in BOTH cases he states that there is a mitzvah to publicly embarrass him - implying that even for בין אדם לחבירו - which is not done habitually it's OK (and commanded) to embarrass him

Comment: The halakhah taught by Rabba b. Rav Huna, is that something said in the presence of three people does not constitute לשון הרע (as it is then public). R. Yonah then takes this is an opportunity to expand upon this theme. He says, though that even where something is said before three, it nevertheless constitutes לשון הרע if it was said לגנות. However, he clarifies, there are times where it is permitted to reveal the truth and publicly shame a person.

Comment: Where a person has inflicted damages and is unrepentant then it is permitted to expose him in order to facilitate his teshuvah. My takeaway is that according to R. Yonah, saying something against a person is אונאת דברים only where there is no תועלת (e.g. it is לגנות, it is vengeful, etc.). Where there is a legitimate תועלת (e.g. to facilitate the teshuvah of the perpetrator/ restore the victim), it does not constitute אונאת דברים and one may publicly state the truth. In other words, the intent is an element of אונאת דברים. This prism is applicable whether it is בין אדם לחבירו or בין אדם למקום.

Comment: I agree that it seems that RY holds that there is no אונאת דברים if לתועלת  - even if person is still בכלל עמיתך - which seems to be a **chiddush**,  which sparked the Q in the OP --> where's the source for this?  Perhaps he agrees with Reb Elchonon in Kovetz Haaros on Yevamos siman 70 that בין אדם לחבירו are permitted if done to help the person - and perhaps getting him to do teshuvah qualifies (though if so why does he mention in Shaarei Teshuvah the reason that he's not בכלל עמיתך?)